# Attempting to output records using a procedure, MySQL PL/SQL

Tags: mysql, oracle

```
CREATE    PROCEDURE      getcustomerdetails     (
d_Fname             OUT        VARCHAR2,
d_Lname             OUT        VARCHAR2,
d_date_signed       OUT        DATE,
d_id                IN         VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN
SELECT     Fname,

Lname,

date_signed

INTO     d_Fname,

d_Lname,

d_date_signed

FROM     customer

WHERE    id     =    d_id;

END      getcustomerdetails;
/
DECLARE
l_id             customer.id%TYPE    :=     '-90';

l_fname            customer.fname%TYPE;

l_lname           customer.lname%TYPE;

l_date_signed      customer.date_signed%TYPE;

BEGIN

getcustomerdetails     (l_fname,

                       l_lname,

                        l_date_signed,

                        l_id);

 
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line     (

            'First name '

         ||     l_fname        ||     chr   (40)

         ||     'Last name '

         ||     l_lname         ||    chr   (30)

         ||     'Date Signed '

         ||     l_date_signed);

   END;
   /

PROCEDURE     getcustomerdetails 

BEGIN

   SELECT    id,    fname,    lname,    shop,    Date_signed,    average_spend,

FROM    Customers

END;
```

Please    advise

Comment: You've tagged this for two different databases, Oracle and MySQL.  Which one are you actually using?  You've posted a bunch of code but you haven't told us what problem you have.

Comment: Welcome to the SO community. It is impossible to help you solve an issue, when you do not say what is the issue. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the help section [ask].

Comment: Im using MYSql sorry didn't mean to tag oracle. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

`DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` call suggests this is Oracle, after all. If so, your code looks mostly OK:

- the last `PROCEDURE getcustomerdetails` shouldn't exist at all; what is its purpose? You created the procedure already, didn't you?
- output is a little bit *strange*. If you meant to use brackets, you should have concatenated them, directly, without using the `CHR` function. I'd say that it isn't appropriate in this case
- code you posted suggests that you "forgot" to enable output, i.e. `set serveroutput on` in SQL*Plus or SQL Developer, or pushing the "enable output" or similar in any other GUI you might be using.

So: sample table:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE customer
  2  AS
  3     SELECT 'Little' fname,
  4            'Foot' lname,
  5            TRUNC (SYSDATE) date_signed,
  6            -90 id
  7       FROM DUAL;

Table created.
```

Procedure:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE getcustomerdetails (
  2     d_Fname           OUT VARCHAR2,
  3     d_Lname           OUT VARCHAR2,
  4     d_date_signed     OUT DATE,
  5     d_id           IN     VARCHAR2)
  6  IS
  7  BEGIN
  8     SELECT Fname, Lname, date_signed
  9       INTO d_Fname, d_Lname, d_date_signed
 10       FROM customer
 11      WHERE id = d_id;
 12  END getcustomerdetails;
 13  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SQL>
SQL> DECLARE
  2     l_id           customer.id%TYPE := '-90';
  3     l_fname        customer.fname%TYPE;
  4     l_lname        customer.lname%TYPE;
  5     l_date_signed  customer.date_signed%TYPE;
  6  BEGIN
  7     getcustomerdetails (l_fname,
  8                         l_lname,
  9                         l_date_signed,
 10                         l_id);
 11
 12
 13     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
 14           'First name '
 15        || l_fname
 16        || CHR (40)
 17        || 'Last name '
 18        || l_lname
 19        || CHR (30)
 20        || 'Date Signed '
 21        || l_date_signed);
 22  END;
 23  /
First name Little(Last name Foot▲Date Signed 26.03.2021

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help but its saying l_fname needs to be declared in the 4th line, would this be an error when creating the procedure?

Comment: This declaration means that local variable named L_FNAME gets its datatype from table CUSTOMER and its FNAME column.

Comment: Hi thanks that worked! Is there a code which allows me to print all data within the customer table using the procedure created?

Comment: do you know how to do that littlefoot? I tried the code CALL customerdetails('*') but doesn't work

Comment: I know, but only for Oracle. As you commented, you actually use MySQL and I don't know how it works. Anyway: in Oracle, you could do it in a loop and use DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE, or create a function which returns refcursor or a collection. I guess something like that would work in MySQL as well.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks for the help. I think I cracked it but keep getting this error: ORA-04089: cannot create triggers on objects owned by SYS
04089. 00000 -  "cannot create triggers on objects owned by SYS"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to create a trigger on an object owned by SYS.
*Action:   Do not create triggers on objects owned by SYS.

Comment: As you were told: don't create objects in SYS's schema. Create your own user and do whatever you're doing there.

Comment: Thanks littlefoot! By any chance, do you know how to use a procedure to print details of customers?

Comment: Not in MySQL, sorry.

Comment: What about Oracle? I can use that too?

Comment: Apparently, you can not as you said "Im using MYSql sorry didn't mean to tag oracle".